# How to add half link in href?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to create half-links in href means, for example, suppose I want to create code to check Alexa ranking so when user come on my website they enter their website URL to check rank so in this https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/ will come automatically and the URL that enters by the user will add after this link.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you expect to happen (rather than describe it) as well as show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the result from the user in variable and concatenate URL like this:

```
 https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/ + userUrl
```

when the userUrl can be - userUrl = 'walla.com' for example

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
var value = $( this ).val();
 $('.urlPlace').text('https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/' + value);
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
input{
  font-size:18px;
  height: 40px;
}
div{
  color:black;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="urlVal" />

<div class="urlPlace">
</div>
```

**I hope this will help**